# add,delete textboxes and pass variable value in object angular 6

Tags: angular

I have one textbox to act dynamically like add,delete. That values I have to pass like this

```
{
  "itemRows": ['122','189']
}
```

but I am getting result like in this example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3tmfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
{
  "itemRows": [
    {
      "itemname": "1212"
    },
    {
      "itemname": "15545"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried in multiple ways but I couldnot take values without key if someone knows way please help me to figure out of this.

Thanks

Comment: A MatInput text can validate only a text, not an array, it isn't logic. You could iterate the form values to build an array in the end

Comment: Can you give me example?